# using URL of images uploaded to domain host in HTML

Tags: html, css, dns, web

I'm trying to use certain images on my web site, but clearly have not used the correct URL in the HTML/CSS to access the images I uploaded to a directory called 'logos' to my web host account, where as all the HTML/CSS files are in the 'public_html' directory.
What's the correct url to use?

I tried asking the technical support from my web host and I don't think they understood my question...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you are using chrome, check the network-stats (ctrl+shift+j, network-tab) and check which domain is currently called, and which domain your primary scripts are called, and then check how they correlate on filesystem level.

Answer (score 0):

public_html is the common name for the public directory of a webserver. What that means that any file or folder that is **OUTSIDE** of that directory (that is not a child of that directory) won't be accessible from an URL. When you type the url of your webpage, you access the public_html folder. What you have to do is move the 'logos' folder inside the public_html folder. That way you'll be able to access the logos folder from yourdomain.com/logos

Good luck!

Comment: Hey! So I moved everything into the public_html folder -- and tried using background-image: url("mywebsite.com/logos/image.jpg") and its still not showing up - am I still using the wrong url? Do I need a slash before the site name or something?